# which salesforce edition should i purchase and which licenses?

Tags: licenses, user-management, userlicense, sales-cloud, editions

I am new to salesforce and my clients wants to implement salesforce for maintaining their clients, they want basic functionalities so which edition should i suggest?

For example i have 5 sales representatives and 1 Admin, in this case which licenses are required and how many?

It will be stand alone there won't be any connection to other system.

Comment: Does salesforce need to be connected to any other systems or will it be stand alone?

Comment: Other questions that would be relevant - does there need to be process automation in Salesforce?